# P/Invoke code works on WinXP, exception on Win2k8

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

I'm attempting to access a function in a DLL in C# and C++.

C++ is working fine, as is C# on WinXP.  However I'm getting the following error when attempting to access the function on a Win2k8 system:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory
is corrupt.
   at Router.GetAddress()
```

The declaration in C# is:

```
    [DllImport("Constants.dll")]
    static extern String GetAddress();
```

Usage in C# (at the moment) is just outputting it:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetAddress());
```

And the contents of the DLL's function are just:

```
const static WCHAR* szAddress= L"net.tcp://localhost:4502/TestAddress";

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) const WCHAR* GetAddress()
{
     return szAddress;
}
```

I really didn't think there was anything controversial here.  The only thing I can think of is the const return from GetAddress, but I'm not sure how to apply the corresponding keyword to C# as I'm not as familiar with that language yet.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For reference's sake, the accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146017/how-do-i-share-a-constant-between-c-and-c-code is what I'm attempting to implement.

Comment: GetAddress and GetRegistrationAddress are not the same function.  Do you have the actual code that's being executed?

Comment: Cheers. It was meant to be GetAddress there as well obviously. I've fixed that up.  The excerpts above are copied and pasted code, and I've added the C# calling snippet as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this problem using the details in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/4e387bb3-6b99-4b9d-91bb-9ec00c47e3a4.

I changed the declaration to:

```
    [DllImport("Constants.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern int GetAddress(StringBuilder strAddress);
```

The usage therefore became:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000000); // Arbitrary length for the time being
GetAddress(sb);
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

And the DLL was changed to:

```
const static WCHAR* szAddress = L"net.tcp://localhost:4502/TestAddress";

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GetAddress(WCHAR* strAddress)
{
     wcscpy(strAddress, szAddress);
     return 0;
}
```