# How to pass const int from managed C++ DLL to C# for use as field value in an attribute

Tags: c#, c++, dll, unmanaged, managed

I have a const int that is computed at compile time in my Managed C++ DLL.  I need to use this value in an attribute within the C# program that calls it.  Initially I had created a static method that returns the const int value but C# doesn't see this as a compile time const.  I also tried declaring it as a const int within the DLL namespace

```
// C++
namespace MyNameSpace {
    const int AttributeConstValue = 15 + sizeof(int);
 . . .
}
```

Attempts to access MyNameSpace.AttributeConstValue from C# returns "does not exist in namespace MyNameSpace"

Is there a way to pass a const to C# and have it see it as a const expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the C++/CLI **literal** keyword to declare public constants that are visible to other managed compilers.  And it must appear inside a ref class.  Like this:

```
namespace Example {
    public ref class Constants {
    public:
        literal int AttributeConstValue = 15 + sizeof(int);
    };
}
```

Sample C# usage:

```
[MyAttribute(Example.Constants.AttributeConstValue)]
// etc..
```

Beware that this is fairly dangerous.  The literal value gets compiled into the C# assembly's metadata without a reference to your C++/CLI assembly.  So if you make a change to this declaration but *don't* recompile the C# project then you'll have a nasty mismatch.  But as long as you need to use it in an attribute declaration then there's no fix for this.

Comment: We were posting same answer simultaneously.  :) Thanks!

Comment: The unsafe condition is mitigated in my case by both the C++ DLL project and C# projects being built within the same solution with the C# project depending on C++ DLL.

Answer (score 0):

`Const` is different then other declaration. When code start to compile - the compiler just replace all places where you use the `const` with it's value - because `const` value could not be changed. It's resolved once - at compilation time and stays that way. I don't really remember but I think optimization flag even delete `const` declaration from code. So the situation is like this: when you done compiling you can not change it - so you first attempt - to return it in some function or getter/setter is right one. Obviously you can not return it to `const` variable because to-return-it you must compile the program and when you compile the program... you get the point :)

P.S. Don't know about C++ but in C# const is `class` members and could not be declared in `namespace`

Comment: You missed that I need to use this constant as the value of a field in an C# **attribute** and using my first technique the C# compiler complained that it was not a constant expression.  See my answer for a solution to this.  Here is the C# usage

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=MyNameSpace.ConstClass.AttributeConstValue]

Comment: @JonN: A `const` variable is *not* a constant expression.  The compiler wants a `constant expression` as it must have this available at compile time.

Comment: @Eds That's true but I wasn't sure how to create a symbolic constant that was usable from C#.  Using the **literal** keyword as Hans points out, in managed C++ makes AttributeConstValue a symbol that is a constant expression.

Comment: @JonN: Yep, I didn't know about `literal` (I know little to nothing of C++/CLI)

Answer (score 0):

Found answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146017/how-do-i-share-a-constant-between-c-sharp-and-c-code)

```
// C++ Const declaration
namespace MyNameSpace {
public ref class ConstClass {
public:
     literal int AttributeConstValue = 15 + sizeof(int);
. . .
}

// C# Usage
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=MyNameSpace.ConstClass.AttributeConstValue)]
public byte [] results;
```

Referencing MyNameSpace.ConstClass.AttributeConstValue as field value for C# attribute works fine using this technique.  The value is seen as a compile time constant expression.